# Making a text view movable inside a layout

Tags: android-layout

How to make dynamically created textview movable inside a relativelayout in android??

Comment: You are going to have to be more specific in your question. What do you mean by movable?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know is this:

http://developer.samsung.com/android/technical-docs/2D-Graphics-in-Android

Cheers,